# Visual studio code doesnt give out error after parents function didnt close corectly how to fix?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, error-handling

> so here is the code first off is the construct function after that is the parents function

```
    public construct() //child
{
    super.construct;
    }
```

```
        protected construct() //parent
    {

    }
```

> so the problem is that i DONT get an error even do i gotta need one this is because my class mate gets one and its anoying for him
> i use visual studio code with typescript ive tyed multiple extensions but nothing worked so far down bellow i added an pic of how it suposed to look like

[error immage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDEAa.png)

if you know i will be happy to recieve ur help if u got the same lets share the pain :)

Answer (score 0):

the struct when you want to extend a class should be like:

```js
class Parent {
  constructor(){
    console.log('parent constructor')
  }
  test(){console.log(1)}
}
class Child  extends Parent {
  constructor(){
    console.log('child constructor')
    super();  //super() will call parent's constructor again
  }
}
let p = new Parent();
let c = new Child();
c.test();   //use super to let the child class can use parents property
```

hope this is helpful

Comment: what i got up there is 2 scripts but my intention was to show where the error gotta acure i got 2 scripts but its part of an big project so i cant show full script but the problem is that i dont get an error if i dont put parentheses after the super function

Comment: you shoud just use `super()`, not `super.construcotr`

Comment: construct is an function name but its more the error that i wanna get but dont get 

if i use  `super.construct; ` i want to get an error that says i need to use `() `because its an function

it needs to be spelled out like this  `super.construct(); `